# How to use Windows Workflow Foundation for send mails

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I would like to implement  Windows Workflow Foundation for my application so whats the best way to implement it.

I.e. 
- My rules is Get users from database based on location.
- Action is Send mail (need to define mail contents)

So please let me know, how can accomplish it using WWF.

Answer (score 1):

WF does not provide neither a "Send email" or a "Read from database" activities out of the box.

You can use [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/SendEmailCustomActivity.aspx) from CodeProject and include it in your workflow.